# Loading wrong xib after updating the app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xib

I already have my app on the App Store and I want to publish a new internationalized version. So, I created a xib for the english version and a xib for the french one (localized in the good en.lproj and fr.lproj folders). And when I set up the app on my iPhone that already have the first no-internationalized version, I had some troubles with the interface : the app does not update all the changes on the UI and I still have french labels even if I set the iPhone language to English (the app does not choose automatically the good xib).

If I only clean the project and build again, it still does not work but when I cleaned my project, deleted the app of the phone and build again, everything works like a charm. I don't want that the problem occurs to people who already have the app and update it via the App Store :/ is there a way to understand what happens ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what happens: In your old version, you have one .xib file in the application bundle, and the bundle looks like this:

```
 <bundle-path>/interface.xib
```

In the new version you have the two localized versions of this file and your bundle looks like this:

```
 <bundle-path>/fr.lproj/interface.xib
 <bundle-path>/en.lproj/interface.xib
```

When the app tries to load the xib file it looks directly in the bundle directory first and, if it doesn't find the file there, looks for the file in the subdirectories with the localized files.

If you have the old version on the device and then build and run the new version from Xcode, legacy files are **not** deleted, so you end up with this bundle

```
 <bundle-path>/interface.xib
 <bundle-path>/fr.lproj/interface.xib
 <bundle-path>/en.lproj/interface.xib
```

and the app loads the unlocalized file as it never needs to look into the localization subdirectories.

I assume that legacy files are not deleted when you deploy from Xcode to a development device for performance reasons.

However, your users will not run into this problem. When a user installs an update of your app, the app bundle will be completely replaced by your new bundle. So if you upload a "clean" bundle without legacy files, and this version works when you do a fresh install on a your device, it will also work on your users' devices.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But how can I install a clean bundle without legacy files ? In order to test my version :)

Comment: Delete the app from the device before you build and install with Xcode.

Comment: Ok and if I understand, if it works like that, it will works for all the users who update ?